# clear all spam form inputs or mark as read

Tags: plugin-freeform, spam

Is there somebody who could help with an sql query or a how-to to clean up our spam form inputs in a quick way, there are +/-5900 unread spam messages from last years and i want to clean them up.

We could do it by Forms > Spam and select all (max 100) and do this 60times but it doesn't sound the fastest way.

There are different tables with links to this entries.

Running craftcms version: 3.4.20 on PHP 7 with Mysql

Comment: Are you using a plugin for your forms? If so, which one?

Comment: I don't think so but when i check plugins, there is also freefrom version 3.6.9 in the list. In the database the freeform tables are used also, so yes we are using that plugin.

Comment: Craft doesn't have a "Forms" menu item in the control panel by default, which is why I figured you're using a plugin. I don't know anything about Freeform myself, but I added the `plugin-freeform` tag to your question to increase visibility. You might consider getting in touch with the plugin vendor (Solspace) as well – https://solspace.com/contact-us

Answer (score 1):

Freeform has a purge spam submissions command to run with your terminal. https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/developer/console-commands.html#purge-commands